# How do I shutdown android Binder threads?

Tags: android

When I profile my app in the Android Device Monitor I see Binder_1 Binder_2 Binder_3. What is the correct way to shut-down these threads when I no longer need them, to conserve resources. Executors have a method, shutdown that can be used to clean up all resources. Is there a similar thing in Android? Thanks in advance!

Comment: binders are threads used internally to bind stuff between processes. you don't shut them down, nor do *you* need them

Comment: Over time it looks like the number of the number of these threads increases though which seems like a leak to me. Also if I don't need them is there a way to prevent them from being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to shut-down these threads when I no longer need them, to conserve resources

You don't. Those are managed by the framework, not you.

Moreover, since the binder threads are usually blocking, outside of some minor amount of heap space, I am unclear what resources you expect to conserve.

> Over time it looks like the number of the number of these threads increases though which seems like a leak to me

Produce a demo app that reproduces the behavior and [file an issue](http://b.android.com) providing the demo app's source code, steps to reproduce the problem, and what environment(s) you tested it on. Bonus points if you can reproduce it on an official Android SDK emulator or a Nexus-series device.

> Also if I don't need them is there a way to prevent them from being created?

I have no idea how you have determined whether or not you need them. After all, if your app is going to run, it will need binder threads to do so, to receive incoming communications from core OS processes (e.g., broadcast `Intents`, `startActivity()` requests). Again, they are managed by the framework, not you.

Comment: Thank you for that very thorough answer! I was under the impression it was leaking because I thought I was creating the threads. I couldn't find any documentation on if I needed to shut them down or not. Thank you.